# How to add swipe actions for table view cell in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I want to add Edit action to display when the user swipes a table row. I used to be able to use the [`tableView(_:editActionsForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614956-tableview) method, but it is now deprecated. And in the [`tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614871-tableview) method, there is no action I need. How can I add actions for my cells?

Comment: The solution provided in the linked answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73559407/5546378 seems to be a viable option for your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let item = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
            //Write your code in here
        }
        item.image = UIImage(named: "deleteIcon")

        let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [item])
    
        return swipeActions
    }
```

Comment: Thx, it works. Maybe you know how to add Image for this button? Image like Trash or other, you know.

Answer (score -1):

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
    }

    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Disable") { (action, indexPath) in
        // share item at indexPath
    }

    share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    return [delete, share]
}
```

Note that the first button uses a `.destructive` style so it will be colored red by default, but the second button specifically has a blue color assigned to it.

Comment: This has been deprecated since iOS 13. The question even mentions that this is deprecated and is looking for the newer solution.