# SwipeActions does not work in tableView swift 5 xcode 13.4.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

i am doing trailingSwipe to my tableview but it does not work. does not call the function `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`.

try with the `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` and if it works for me but not with **trailingSwipe**

valid that I have delegate and datasource the tableview

code

```html
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "delete2") {(action, view, completionHandler) in
            print("delete2 \(indexPath.row)")
        }
        let swipe = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
        return swipe
    }
```

Uses Apple Mac M1 ( MacBook Pro M1)

Comment: Using iphone to respond, had similar issue had to implement canEdit and return yes.

Comment: Please check this edited answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73550696/9331686

Answer (score 6):

Try this, working fine on the Xcode 13+, Apple Mac M1 and Swift 5

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
} 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
      //  print("index path of delete: \(indexPath)")
        
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    let edit = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { [weak self] (action, sourceView, completionHandler)  in
        
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    delete.title = ""
    delete.image = UIImage(named: "deleteProfile")
    
    edit.title = ""
    edit.image = UIImage(named: "editProfile")
    
    let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete,edit])
    swipeAction.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false // This is the line which disables full swipe
    return swipeAction
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue on my end.
Maybe this issue is with the `Apple Mac M1` please try with the `Apple intel`.

Please check this [question](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693731)

Below code is working fine in my Apple Intel.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "REMOVE") { [self] action, view, completion in
            // Your swipe action code!
            completion(true)
        }
    
    action.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    
    let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
    swipeAction.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false        // Full swipe disable
    
    return swipeAction
}
```

> I found a solution in Apple M1 please try it with the Real device.

I tried the above code on a `real device` it's working perfectly.

Comment: with the Real device it works, but not in the simulator