# UITableViewDelegate method for swipe actions is not called at iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, swipe

I use a `tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)` method in order to add swipe-to-delete gesture in iOS app. It works as expected at iOS 16.2 simulator. But in iOS 13.7 simulator it does not show any actions on swipe.

The method is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { [weak self] action, view, handler in
            self?.presenter.requestDeletion(at: indexPath.row)
        }
        
        let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
        return config
    }
```

I've set breakpoints inside the method and they are not even called on swipe. Swipes at iOS 16.2 trigger the breakpoints.

Comment: Does it do anything on a right-to-left swipe under iOS 13.7? Any messages in the console? That delegate methods works in one of my apps when testing on an iOS 13.5 simulator (I don't have 13.7 installed). You should post your full delegate method.

Comment: No messages in the console.

Comment: If all you want is a Delete button then try using the older style cell deletion. Make sure the `canEdit` data source method returns true (the default), `editingStyle` delegate method returns `.delete` (the default), and you implement the `commit` data source method.

Comment: I've found the solution without the old style. Anyway, thanks for your help, it was a start in the right direction 

Comment: The solution provided in the linked answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73559407/5546378) seems to be a viable option for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's necessary to return `true` from the `tableView(_:canEditRowAt:)` data source method, and swipe actions work as expected.

Comment: Odd. If you don't implement the `canEditRowAt` data source method it defaults to true. And the behavior should be the same across different iOS versions.

Comment: Yup. But it works. Maybe it behaves this way because I use `UITableViewDiffableDataSource`, I don't know.

Comment: I return true from `canEditRowAt:`, but it still does not work in the simulator. It does work on a real device. I think it is a bug in the simulator.